# Drop rows in dask dataFrame on condition

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, data-analysis, dask

I'm trying to drop some rows in my dask dataframe with :

```
df.drop(df[(df.A <= 3) | (df.A > 1000)].index)
```

But this one doesn't work and return `NotImplementedError: Drop currently only works for axis=1`

I really need help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can remove rows from a Pandas/Dask dataframe as follows:

```
df = df[condition]
```

In your case you might do something like the following:

```
df = df[(df.A > 3) & (df.A <= 1000)]
```